# numpy.lib.format.open_memmap not storing data

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-memmap

My numpy.lib.format.open_memmap is not storing my data. Code is below.

```
>>> from numpy.lib.format import open_memmap
>>> import numpy as np
>>> winners = open_memmap("winners.npy", dtype = np.str_, mode='w+', shape=(6,))
>>> winners[0] = "emma"
>>> winners
memmap(['', '', '', '', '', ''], dtype='<U0') # why is this empty?
```

I also tried flushing winners.

```
>>> winners.flush()
>>> winners
memmap(['', '', '', '', '', ''], dtype='<U0') # still empty.
```

Comment: Specify a string size, e.g. 'U10'

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: `dtype = np.str_`  is defaulting to 'U0'

Comment: You can use, for example, `dtype='U8'`, which will allow for unicode strings of up to length 8.

Comment: `memmap` has to be big enough to hold the strings that you want to put there.  `numpy` string dtype has a fixed (maximum) size, which you need to specify when creating the array.

Comment: How do I store strings of dynamic lengths?

Comment: You can't.  Python strings can be of any length, but `numpy` can only "store" those as `object` dtype, which isn't allowed with `memmap`.  `numpy` string dtype has a fixed maximum size.